# I set url to blank=null but it says url is required field

Tags: python, django

Edit 1

Models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    content = FroalaField()
    url = models.URLField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    moderator = models.ForeignKey(User)
    rank_score = models.FloatField(default= 1)

    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images",blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    objects = models.Manager()            # default manager

    @property
    def domain(self):
        return urlparse(urlsplit(self.url)).netloc if self.url else "a"
```

Here;s my forms.py

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="plz enter")

    url = forms.URLField(max_length=200,
                         help_text="Please enter the URL of the page.")
    views = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)
    content = forms.CharField(widget=FroalaEditor)
    class Meta:
        model = Post

        exclude = ['pub_date', 'moderator', 'rank_score', 'image','slug']
```

I get invalid syntax error from here:           return urlparse(urlsplit(self.url)).netloc if self.url else "a"

Comment: Show us full codes and error messages

Comment: @AbuAshrafMasnun I just posted my full code, I don't get error message. It just says url field is required if I just leave empty.

Comment: have you run migrations/syncdb and restarted the server?

Comment: same thing....why is this happening url field has null for both...

Comment: Try removing the .pyc files

Comment: I don't have any pyc files...what are they/>

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
url = forms.URLField(max_length=200,
                         help_text="Please enter the URL of the page.")
```

to:

```
url = forms.URLField(max_length=200,
                     help_text="Please enter the URL of the page.",
                     required=False)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the solution. There are so many things like that in django, do you know how to fix the first problem I posted?  return urlparse(self.url).netloc if self.url is not None else "d",,,should return d if url is not inserted but wont return d....

Comment: That may be because you wrote `is not None`, and `self.url` can actually equal `''` (an empty string, which is not the same as None). Try `return urlparse(self.url).netloc if not self.url else "d"`

Answer (score 0):

You are using a ModelForm so should not have to override the url field in your Form.

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'url', 'views', 'content', 'moderator', 'slug', 'objects')
        widgets = {
            'content': FroalaEditor(),  # Not sure if this widget is valid
            'views':forms.HiddenInput()
        }
```

You can also add your helptext to your models (see [`help_text` docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#help-text))

Comment: Hello do you know how to fix the first problem I posted? return urlparse(self.url).netloc if self.url is not None else "d",,,should return d if url is not inserted but wont return d..

Comment: Try `return urlparse(self.url).netloc if self.url else "d"`. What is it returning? Is it throwing an error? If so, a stack trace would be useful.

Comment: hmm I tried return urlsplit(urlparse(self.url)).netloc if self.url else "d", but this gives me error....tried bunch of things...it says invalid syntax...but this is right python no?

Comment: Why don't you add the errors you are getting, and any updates you have made to your code (if any), to the original question?

Comment: Thanks for being patience with me, I just edited the code and provided error

Comment: When you paste the code, it is more helpful to put the whole error. A lot of it might look like garbage but it's pretty useful for debugging. If you think the syntax is wrong for the inline if statement, try using a normal if statement.